# Not able to create more that 7 worker nodes using kops in AWS educate account

Tags: amazon-web-services, kops

Whenever i try to increase minSize above 7 in the nodes instance group  i get the following status in autoscaling groups activity panel.

Cancelled-
Launching a new EC2 instance: i-0a142b29de1102e66. Status Reason: Instance became unhealthy while waiting for instance to be in InService state. Termination Reason: Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown

How can i set up a cluster of more than 10 worker nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS Educate Starter account is **very limited**. The current, non-exhoustive list of the limitations is in:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://awseducate-starter-account-services.s3.amazonaws.com/AWS_Educate_Starter_Account_Services_Supported.pdf)

Probably you are hitting one of these limits.

Comment: I couldn't identify any limit which i am crossing. Is there a way i can review the limits i might be crossing?

Comment: @Ravi The list writes "All services may have additional restrictions not listed below.". Contact your educator or the AWS Educate support.

Comment: Ok. Will contact my educator and verify. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Lemme see if service limits is the issue.

Comment: @Ravi Sure, no rush.